# pagination function initialize not working

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

when i am trying to create pagination in codeigniter . i am recieving an error called to undefined function initialize on null

```
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller
 {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
$this->load->library('pagination');
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('registration');

}

  public function manage()
{
       //$this->session->set_userdata($active);
       $config = array();
       $config["base_url"] =   site_url('admin_controller/manage');
      $config["total_rows"] = $this->db->get('entries_new') ->num_rows();
      $config["per_page"] = 2;
      $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
      $config["num_links"] = 3;
      $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
      $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
      $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
      //echo "<pre>";die(print_r($config));

      $this->pagination->initialize($config);
       $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
      $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['ResAre']=$this->admin_model->get_data($config["per_page"],$page);
       $this->load->view('adminpage',$data);
}
 function register()
{
    if($this->input->post('register'))
    {
        $this->admin_model->insert_data();
        redirect(base_url('index.php/login_controller'));
    }
}

function update()
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['editid']) && $_REQUEST['editid']!='' && $_REQUEST['editid']!=0)
        { 

      $data['ResAre']=$this->admin_model->update();
          $this->load->view('updatepage',$data);
}
   }

    function updated()
    {
      if(isset($_POST['update']))
        {

         $this->admin_model->updated();
         redirect(base_url('index.php/admin_controller/manage')); 

        }
}
function delete()
{
   if(isset($_REQUEST['deleteid']) && $_REQUEST['deleteid']!='' && $_REQUEST['deleteid']!=0)
        {
        // load model
         $this->admin_model->delete();
         redirect(base_url('index.php/admin_controller/manage')); 
         }
  }

 }
```

here is the code where i am getting error i.e called to function initialize on null but i already load library in construct function.Please give me solution where i am wrong

**here is model code**

```
class Admin_Model extends CI_Model
{   
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


public function get_data($limit , $offset)
{

     $query = $this->db->select('*')  ->from('entries_new') ->limit($limit) ->offset($offset) ->get();
    //print_r($query);die;
    return $query->result();
}

public function insert_data()
{
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    //echo $name;die;
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
              $this->db->select('*');  
              $this->db->from('entries_new');
              $this->db->where('name',$name);
    $query = $this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows() == 0)
            {
                $data = ['name'=> $name ,'email'=>$email , 'password'=>$password ,'mobile'=>$mobile];
                $this->db->insert('entries_new',$data);
            }
            else{ return false ;}
}
public function update()
{
           $id=$_REQUEST['editid'];
          $query =  $this->db->select('*') ->from('entries_new') ->where('id', $id) ->get();
            return $result = $query->result();

}
public function updated()
{
        $id=$this->input->post('upid');
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');

        $data=array('name'=>$name, 'email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password,                   'mobile'=>$mobile);
             $this->db->where('id',$id);
             $this->db->update('entries_new',$data);
             return true;
}
 function delete()
{
    $id=$_REQUEST['deleteid'];
       $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('entries_new');

}
```

**view page**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap.min.css" 
 rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3"></div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <h2 align="center">HOME</h2>
 <h4 align="center"> Welcome !!!!!!!!!! </h4>
 <form>
 <div class="table-responsive" >
 <table border="0" align="center" class="table" style="border:1px solid 
 darkorange;">        
 <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php $i=0;
    //  print_r($records); die;
    foreach($ResAre as $row)
    {   ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->mobile;?></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin_controller/update');? 
    >?editid=<?php echo $row->id; ?> ">Edit</a> | <a href="<?php echo 
    base_url('index.php/admin_controller/delete');?>?deleteid=<?php echo 
    $row->id;?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr> <?php  $i++;} ?>
    <td colspan="6">
    <div align="center"><a href="<?php echo 
    base_url('index.php/admin_controller');?>">ADD</a></div></td>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div align="center"><a href='<?php echo 
    base_url('index.php/login_controller/logout'); ?>' > Logout</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where u passing offset and limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

in your model :

First : in `admin_model` you are extending it with `CI_Controller` ,change it `CI_Model`

```
   class Admin_Model extends CI_Model
   {   
      public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
      }

      /* `get_data()` should be like this:*/
      public function get_data($limit, $start)
      {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->select('*')  ->from('entries_new') ->get();
        //print_r($query);die;
        return $query->result();
      }     
   }
```

Second : set limit and offset in `get_data()` method both in `controller` and `model`

```
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] =   site_url('admin_controller/manage');
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->db->get('entries_new')->num_rows();
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config["num_links"] = 3;
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    /* pass offest and limit here if not passing*/
    $data["ResAre"] = $this->admin_model->get_data($config["per_page"],$page);

    $data["pagination"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('adminpage',$data);
```

Comment: actually i forgot to put limit ,offset now i fixed it . but after that error still remains the same please have a glance on a code

Comment: where u exactly getting the error and what error , pls be precise

Comment: getting error line number 33 i.e `$this->pagination->initialize($config);` and error_handler says **Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on null in C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\controllers\admin_controller.php on line 33**

Comment: u r extending model to CI_controller change it to CI_model see my updated answer